# Can I call Cypher's .Return with a Func<>?

Tags: c#, neo4jclient

I'm working with the Neo4jClient for C# and it works brilliantly ! Thanks Tatham Oddie.

At runtime, I need to return different results based on some criteria though. I see Return is defined and overloaded as basically:

```
ICypherFluentQuery<TResult> Return<TResult>(Expression<Func<ICypherResultItem, TResult>> expression);
```

Since TResult is a templated param, I'm not sure how I could create a Func<> that I can pass to .Return

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
Func<ICypherResultItem, User> returnCode = (user) => new { u = user.As<User> } ;

var query = client
    .Cypher
    .Start(new { root = client.RootNode })
    .Match("root-[:HAS_BOOK]->user");
    .Return(   returnCode );
```

Is this possible ? How can I declare the Func<> to pass to Return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `returnCode` variable as `Expression<>>` and compiler will generate expression for you:

> When a lambda expression is assigned to a variable, field, or parameter whose type is `Expression<TDelegate>`, the compiler emits instructions to build an expression tree.
>
> *from [Expression Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*

But because your lambda returns [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), instead of `User` class instance, your `Func<T, TRresult>` generic parameter does not match. Try with following:

```
Expression<Func<ICypherResultItem, User>> returnCode = (user) => user.As<User>;
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin ! That works, just compiled and ran it. Cant believe I didnt notice the Expression<> portion that wrapped the func in the client code. There were so many parameters (16) that I probably didnt notice them. Thanks again !!!